# Crashlytics task cannot be added to gradle tasks

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, google-fabric

I installed Crashlytics plugin to Android Studio project, but the gradle task crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug is not added to gradle tasks.
How can I add to gradle tasks?

Installing Crashlytics is successed, but the command below is failed.

```
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug' not found in root project 'MyProject'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.02 secs
```

My build.gradle setting is below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName:"@string/app_name", iconLabel:"@string/icon_label"]
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 20
        versionName "2.0.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix '-dev'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        develop {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName:"@string/dev_app_name", iconLabel:"@string/dev_icon_label"]
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV_ENV", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "XXX", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
        staging {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName:"@string/stg_app_name", iconLabel:"@string/stg_icon_label"]
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV_ENV", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "XXX", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
        production {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV_ENV", "false"
            buildConfigField "String", "XXX", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'                           
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'                            
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'         
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'                      
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'             
    compile 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.5-RELEASE'     
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.80.3'                           
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.2' 
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'              
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'                       
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'                   
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'        
    compile 'com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.0.3@aar'                  
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.6.1@aar'                  
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Refer this tutorial this will help you.

https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-crashlytics-for-android-by-fabric-tutorial/

Comment: Any chance you can share your build.gradle? I want to see if anything stands out with how Crashlytics and Fabric are being configured.

Comment: @Saneesh Installing Crashlytics is successed, but the gradle task crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug is not added to gradle tasks.

Comment: @Alexizamerican I added my build.gradle setting.

Comment: Thanks @tama. It looks like you're using very old versions of the plugins. Can you use 1.24.2 of the Fabric gradle plugin and 2.6.8 of Crashlytics? Try modifying your build.gradle and doing a clean build.

Comment: @Alexizamerican Thanks for the suggestion. I upgraded Fabric plugin version and Crashlytics version, but didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you post your full build.gradle (including buildTypes, flavors etc?) and remove any sensitive data?

Comment: @Alexizamerican I updated build.gradle to including buildTypes and flavors.

Comment: I upgraded SDK version to 26, but couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have configure develop, staging and production to productFlavors, so need to add productFlavor to the command.

Below is correct command.

./gradlew assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistribution[**flavor**]Debug

e.g.

```
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevelopDebug
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevelopDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDevelopDebugManifest
:app:preDevelopReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProductionDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProductionReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preStagingDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE

・
・
・

:app:compileStagingDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileStagingDebugSources
:app:transformClassesWithDexForStagingDebug
:app:mergeStagingDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForStagingDebug
:app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForStagingDebug
:app:processStagingDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForStagingDebug
:app:validateSigningStagingDebug
:app:packageStagingDebug
:app:assembleStagingDebug
:app:assembleDebug
:app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevelopDebug
Uploading /my_android_project_path/app/build/outputs/apk/app-develop-debug.apk to Crashlytics...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 23.897 secs
```