# Fabric "crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug" is not there

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have just updated a project to have `debug` and `release` buildTypes, all working well till now expect the `crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug` task is not in the project and all other crashlytics tasks are there

using `fabricPlugin : '1.28.1'`

`Task 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug' not found in root project`

```
crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug
crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease
crashlyticsUploadDeobsDebug
crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease
crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

---

android project `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'

apply from: '../coverage.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion versions.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

        versionCode buildInfo.number
        versionName buildInfo.name

        minSdkVersion versions.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion versions.targetSdk

        //Fabric
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = buildInfo.releaseNotes
        ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-debug'
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    xxxxxx
    implementation(libraries.crashlytics) {
        transitive true
    }
    xxxxx
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339588/crashlytics-task-cannot-be-added-to-gradle-tasks

If not please provide your gradle file (without sensitive data please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found there is property in the debug build type set to false

```
        debug {
            ...
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            ...
        }
```

when removed or switched to true the debug task will be available :| 
sorry my bad